# Comparing the colors of different objects in SceneKit

Tags: xcode, swift, scenekit

I'm developing a simple game with SceneKit. After having created a nxn grid of spheres (each having one of five random colors) the player selects three of them in a row, and if they have the same color then they are removed from the grid. I'm fine with the selection part of the code, but I can't manage to compare the colors of the trio to check if it is valid. The function that I'm using is

```
func respondToPanGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    var colorsTrio = Array<NSObject>()

    var numberOfWhiteSpheres: Int {
        var count = 0   
        for child in scnView.scene!.rootNode.childNodes {
            let materials = child.geometry?!.materials as! [SCNMaterial]
            let material = materials[0]
            if  material.diffuse.contents as! NSObject == UIColor.whiteColor(){
                count++
            }
        }
        return count
    }

    if let panGesture = gesture as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {

        let location = gesture.locationInView(scnView)

        let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(location, options: nil)
        if hitResults?.count > 0 && (numberOfWhiteSpheres < 3) {
            let result = hitResults![0] as! SCNHitTestResult
            let node = result.node
            SCNTransaction.begin()
            SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(1.0)
            let materials = node.geometry?.materials as! [SCNMaterial]
            let material = materials[0]
            colorsTrio.append(material.diffuse.contents as! [UIColor])
            material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.whiteColor()
            SCNTransaction.commit()

        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to store the color properties of my spheres in an array to then compare them using another function. I can successfully build the program, but once I start selecting one of the spheres I encounter the following bug: "Could not cast value of type 'UICachedDeviceRGBColor' (0x101ebfd80) to 'NSArray' (0x100af4470)." I understand that it's not possible to append that property to my array. Any ideas on how I could circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because of this line:

```
colorsTrio.append(material.diffuse.contents as! [UIColor])
```

The object in `material.diffuse.contents` is a single instance of (a subclass of) `UIColor`, and you're trying to cast it to an array of instances of `UIColor`. The [`Array.append`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Array_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structm/Array/s:FSa6appendurFRGSaq__Fq_T_) method takes an element as its parameter, not another array of elements, so you can fix this error by changing your cast:

```
colorsTrio.append(material.diffuse.contents as! UIColor)
```

**However, this is still not a great idea.** Colors are a very fuzzy thing to be comparing. (Is `#FF0000` really a different enough red from `#FE0000` for your purposes? What about the same RGB values in different color spaces?) In the program you've described, you have a few colors with a semantic distinction in their meaning — you care about the difference between a red sphere and a blue sphere, not subtle distinctions between color spaces and component values.

In any game, it's a good idea to make the gameplay model independent of the display — you want to be able to test your logic for matching spheres separately from the code that puts them on the screen. So make a model that includes your semantic color values. For example:

```
enum Color {
    case Red, Yellow, White /* ... etc ... */
}
class GameNode: SCNNode {
    var color: Color
    // ...
}

// elsewhere...
let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(location, options: nil) as! [SCNHitTestResult]
if let result = hitResults.first {
    if let node = result.node as GameNode {
        colorsTrio.append(node.color)
        // ...
    }
}

// still elsewhere...
if (colorsTrio[0] == colorsTrio[1] && colorsTrio[1] == colorsTrio[2]) {
    // match!
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I actually tried to do something like that but had a few problems with inheritances . When you say elsewhere you mean in a different class, right?

Answer (score 1):

you are eating `material.diffuse.contents` to `[UIColor]` (i.e. an array of colors). Shouldn't it be just `UIColor` ?

```
material.diffuse.contents as! UIColor
```